# Is there a way to always show rounded corners on a form section?

Tags: swiftui

I'm using the default form with a section inside of it. When I increase the device font size to accessibility extra large, the rounded corners and margins disappear. I was wondering if there is a way to always keep them.

[Normal section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTspr.png)
[Section with increased font size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6InMN.png)